# Rearranging terms in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Hi I don't fully need help with the question as I know what to do however I don't understand one of the steps on the picture I sent hence why I can't solve this problem. I have a written solution too which uses a similar method and again I don't understand it for the same reasons.

It says solve for dv(x)/dx however I don't know why I can't seem to be able to rearrange it to that answer. Any help will be appreciated Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the only place you're stuck is "Solve for $\frac{dv(x)}{dx}$". So:

$2x^2(x\frac{dv(x)}{dx}+v(x))=x^2(v(x)^2+1)$

We divide by $2x^2$:

$x\frac{dv(x)}{dx}+v(x)=\frac{1}{2}(v(x)^2+1)$

Subtract $v(x)$:

$x\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}(v(x)^2+1) - v(x)$

And divide by $x$:

$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}(\frac{1}{2}(v(x)^2+1) - v(x))$

Now to make the $v(x)$ term part of the entire fraction, we multiply by 2/2:

$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}(\frac{1}{2}(v(x)^2+1-2v(x)))=\frac{1}{2x}(v(x)^2+1-2v(x))$

Which is the result in the next step.

Comment: It was a sneaky bracket ahhh well maybe not for you.  Thank you so much